# Is 3 rounds more secure than 2 in this simplified DES?

Tags: block-cipher, des

> Consider the following simplification of DES: a plaintext message block of $2n$ bits of length is divided into two blocks of length $n$ (left half $L_0$ and right half $L_1$). In other words, the input to the algorithm is $L_0 \mathbin{\|}L_1$, where $\mathbin{\|}$ denotes concatenation. The same key $K$ of $n$ bits is used in all rounds. The function $f(L,K) = L \oplus K$ (bitwise, modulo 2 addition) is used instead of the standard DES function. One round of encryption takes the input $L_i\mathbin{\|}L_{i+1}$ and produces the output $L_{i+1} \mathbin{\|} L_{i+2}$, where $L_{i+2} =L_i \oplus f(L_{i+1},K)$.
>
> 1. Describe how would Bob perform decryption of this scheme.
> 2. What is more secure, using two rounds or three rounds? Justify your answer, and point out what is the most important weakness of the proposed scheme.
>
> Is it possible to use only 2 rounds in this case?

Comment: This is obviously not something you wrote. Please [provide proper attribution for quoted material](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Is your question just “Is it possible to use only 2 rounds?”, or are you expecting us to do the whole assignment? What have you done so far about decryption and about the impact of the number of rounds?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about it and yes this is a question and I haven't written it. The main thing I wanted to know is the second part whether 3 rounds would be more secure than 2 and is it possible to use only 2 rounds as after searching, I could not find an example where only 2 or 3 rounds have been used.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the professor is expecting you to notice a particularly simple relation between input and output after 3 rounds - what is that relationship?

Comment: To answer which is more secure, well, we observe that with 2 rounds, an attacker can recover the key $K$ with a single known plaintext/ciphertext pair; against 3 rounds, he cannot...